# detect if the user switched to NO in location services

Tags: android, networking, gps

I have a code which redirects to settings if GPS or network is not enabled.The problem is that I want to either programmatically enforce location service when the alert dialog detects that GPS is not enabled or detect the option user has selected in location services and then redirect back to the calling activity.Also I want the location to be checked every 10 seconds until the particular activity is on.please help me

My GPS Checking method

```
 public void setGPSLocation()
{
    GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(FormBuilderActivity.this);
    // check if GPS enabled
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){
        latitude_loc = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude_loc = gps.getLongitude();

        // \n is for new line
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        latitude_loc = 0.00;
        longitude_loc = 0.00;
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        gps.showSettingsAlert();

    }
}
```

GPSTracker.class

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
private final Context mContext;
// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;
Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude
// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute
// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;
public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager                                   .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return location;
}
/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}
/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}
/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}
/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}
/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");
    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Please go to settings and switch on the location fetching service");
    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

            //turnGPSOn();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    // on pressing cancel button
    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Why not use the 'onLocationChanged()' method instead of checking location every 10 seconds, in your GPSTracker class.

Comment: i dont want to detect change in location.I just want to detect if the location service is turned off in settings when the user opens settings and selects no.

Comment: For that you can use other methods, onProviderDisabled, onProviderEnabled. They will serve your pupose.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Turn On GPS!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TURN_ON_GPS_ACTIVITY);
}
```

In your onActivityResult :

```
case TURN_ON_GPS_ACTIVITY:
            //check gps state
            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                //Here : when user comes back from settings without switching on GPS
                // Do as you please, either take them again to settings or show some warning message.

            }
```

I hope this will serve your purpose.

Comment: how do I handle OnActivityResult in service

Comment: Then onProviderDisabled() you can ask user to turn on gps!